# Need to encode ISCII91 Byte Array but don't have Charsets.jar on OpenJDK 11

Tags: java

I was wondering if Charsets.jar is available on OpenJDK?  If it is, how do I get it?  Or is it still licensed under Oracle?  I need to decode Hindi byte arrays encoded in ISCII91.  (That is - convert them to UTF)